# 500 Response for GA4 Events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've been getting some 500 responses for GTM-related GA4 requests on my site, and (despite a lot of Googling) can't figure out where to start diagnosing the issue in order to fix it. I know SO isn't intended for such open-ended questions; I'd nonetheless appreciate guidance on how to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Can you show full parameters and you can hide the parameters value if you want but keep the parameter key remains.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, altougth my configuration is in spanish yo can search the translation. The problem is that the users are giving interations without make a hit into the page, so you´re analytics its showing a lot of information. Read about the hit iteraction when you configure an event from Universal Analytics, this is the setup or the configure initial

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A64J.png)